# IAP Request - Trigger a DAG throughout a cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer, google-iap

Morning, I'm trying to make a POST request to IAP which then Triggers a DAG, however, I'm having the following error:

[image]

It happens when I try this:

```
make_iap_request(
        webserver_url, client_id, method='POST', json={"conf": data, "replace_microseconds": 'false'})


def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method, **kwargs):
    if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['timeout'] = 90

    google_open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), client_id)

    resp = requests.request(
        method, url,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
            google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
```

Can someone help me, please?

Kind regards,
Juliano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errorno 11001 can pop up when url cannot be resolved.

Url from the screenshot seems to be strange as there is `appspot.com` twice. I think this not proper URL at all. URL syntax you can find on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). I think that except host part it cannot contain dots.

Please verify the url you are invoking in the code.

Comment: morning @vitooh, I didn't see that. I will check it out now, as soon as possible I will let you know if I made it.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was setting up incorrectly my URL as u said. 
:)